# linux sed how to wrap a multiline search pattern with text

Tags: sed

I have a html file which includes a section as follows:

```
<div id='webnews'>
... variable stuff ...
</div>
```

which I want to comment out as follows:

```
<!--
<div id='webnews'>
 ... variable stuff ...
</div>
-->
```

I can find & print the multiline text as follows:

```
sed '/<div id="webnews"/, /<\/div>/ { p }' filename.html
```

Experimenting with h, d, x and G, I have been unable work out how to either wrap the hold buffer or the pattern buffer with `'<!--' and '-->'`.

Would appreciate help with this challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick and dirty with sed (not the best idea on html unless you are sure of html content/structure)

```
sed "/<div id='webnews'/, /<\/div>/ {
  /<div id='webnews'/ { 
     h
     d
     }
  H 
  /<\/div>/ !d
  x
  s/^/<!--\\
/
  s/$/\\
-->/
  }" filename.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Sed is not the right tool for the job.

Use [sift](https://sift-tool.org/samples):

`sift -m '(.+)(<div id=.webnews.>.*</div>)(.+)' --replace '$1<!-- $2 -->$3'`

Comment: Nice tool. Unfortunately it extracts data which matches the pattern rather than replacing within the output stream and is also greedy on the terminating pattern capturing far more than intended.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/<div id='\''webnews'\''>/,/<\/dev>/!b;/<div id='\''webnews'\''>/i\<!--' -e '/<\/div>/a\-->' file
```

Or perhaps:

```
sed $'/<div id=.webnews.>/,/<\/dev>/{/<div id=.webnews.>/i\<!--\n;/<\/div>/a\-->\n}' file
```